# XUnit runs forever on Azure DevOps when there is more than one test class, but runs ok locally

Tags: c#, azure-devops, xunit.net

I have an Integration test that runs successfully locally, but is frozen on Azure DevOps.

If there is only one test class, it runs on Azure DevOps.

```
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.1 (64-bit .NET Core 4.6.27414.05)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.04]   Discovering: myapp.IntegrationTests
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.12]   Discovered:  myapp.IntegrationTests
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.13]   Starting:    myapp.IntegrationTests
Passed   myapp.IntegrationTests.class1.case1
[xUnit.net 00:00:04.39]   Finished:    myapp.IntegrationTests
Passed   myapp.IntegrationTests.class1.case2
Results File: D:\a\1\s\TestResults\VssAdministrator_fv-az601_2019-05-02_16_54_26.trx

Total tests: 2. Passed: 2. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
Test Run Successful.
Test execution time: 6.4121 Seconds
```

However, It is frozen at the last line below when there is more than one test class file.

```
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.1 (64-bit .NET Core 4.6.27414.05)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.72]   Discovering: myapp.IntegrationTests
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.78]   Discovered:  myapp.IntegrationTests
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.79]   Starting:    myapp.IntegrationTests
```

Below is some info:
Run it locally within VS 2017, it shows below. Please note 4.6.27110.04 is different.

```
[02/05/2019 17:28:48 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.1 (64-bit .NET Core **4.6.27110.04**)
```

The project is .NET Core 2.2

Below is the log of Integration Test Assemblies

```
##[section]Starting: Integration Test Assemblies
==============================================================================
Task         : Visual Studio Test
Description  : Run unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, etc.) using the Visual Studio Test (VsTest) runner. Test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter such as MsTest, xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah (for JavaScript tests using QUnit, Mocha and Jasmine), etc. can be run. Tests can be distributed on multiple agents using this task (version 2).
Version      : 2.150.9
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=835764)
==============================================================================
SystemVssConnection exists true
SystemVssConnection exists true
SystemVssConnection exists true
Running tests using vstest.console.exe runner.
======================================================
Test selector : Test assemblies
Test filter criteria : null
Search folder : D:\a\1\s
VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest
Attempting to find vstest.console from a visual studio installation.
Attempting to find vstest.console from a visual studio build tools installation.
Attempting to find vstest.console from a visual studio installation.
Run in parallel : false
Run in isolation : false
Path to custom adapters : null
Other console options : null
Code coverage enabled : false
Diagnostics enabled : true
SystemVssConnection exists true
Run the tests locally using vstest.console.exe
========================================================
Test selector : Test assemblies
Test assemblies : **\*.IntegrationTests.dll,!**\obj\**
Test filter criteria : null
Search folder : D:\a\1\s
Run settings file : D:\a\1\s
Run in parallel : false
Run in isolation : false
Path to custom adapters : null
Other console options : null
Code coverage enabled : false
Diagnostics enabled : false
Rerun failed tests: false
VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest
Attempting to find vstest.console from a visual studio installation.
Attempting to find vstest.console from a visual studio build tools installation.
Attempting to find vstest.console from a visual studio installation.
========================================================
======================================================
[command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" @D:\a\_temp\89a681e1-6cfc-11e9-a74f-a3bedc500b32.txt
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.9.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

vstest.console.exe 
"D:\a\1\s\src\myapp.IntegrationTests\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\myapp.IntegrationTests.dll"
/logger:"trx"
/TestAdapterPath:"D:\a\1\s"
Starting test execution, please wait...
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.1 (64-bit .NET Core 4.6.27414.05)
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.97]   Discovering: myapp.IntegrationTests
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.03]   Discovered:  myapp.IntegrationTests
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.04]   Starting:    myapp.IntegrationTests
[xUnit.net 00:00:06.47]   Finished:    myapp.IntegrationTests
Passed   myapp.IntegrationTests.class2.case1
Results File: D:\a\1\s\TestResults\VssAdministrator_fv-az606_2019-05-02_17_06_04.trx

Total tests: 1. Passed: 1. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
Test Run Successful.
Test execution time: 8.5422 Seconds
##[section]Async Command Start: Publish test results
Publishing test results to test run '1019422'
Test results remaining: 1. Test run id: 1019422
Published Test Run : https://dev.azure.com/mydomain/_TestManagement/Runs#runId=1019422&_a=runCharts
##[section]Async Command End: Publish test results
##[section]Finishing: Integration Test Assemblies
```

Project references below

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.10.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

The code only uses `[Fact]`, and it is very simple.

Again, it runs forever when there is more than one class.

**Update**

```
public class A : Base
  {
  [Fact]
      public async Task Case1()
      {
      }
  }


    public class B : Base
  {
  [Fact]
      public async Task Case1()
      {
      }
  }


  public class Base
  {

      protected static WebResponse WebResponse { get; set; }

      private static bool IsTrue { get; set; } = true;
      private static readonly object ObjectLock = new object();

      public BaseTest()
      {
          if(IsTrue){


          lock (ObjectLock)
          {
              if (IsTrue){

                  WebResponse = GetWebAsync().Result;
                  IsTrue = false;
              }
          }
      }
      }

  }
```

I need to run the setup within Base class for all subclasses like above, but I think it might cause the issue.

If it is the issue, how to avoid it and improve the code?

Comment: Try to run the pipeline with `system.debug` = true, maybe it will help find the issue.

Comment: Do you mean system.debug=true when queuing it for a build? If so, it is still not working.

Comment: Yes, it shouldn’t solve the issue, just maybe give you more details, maybe with the details you can understand why the issue happens.

Comment: Please see my update on OP.

Answer (score 0):

I set it to below

```
"parallelizeTestCollections": false
```

or set it to run sequentially via `Collection` attribute